# How do you install Epson ET-2550 drivers in 17.04?

Tags: drivers, printing, 17.04

It appears that the required (Epson) lsb  is no longer available.

Comment: What did you try and what was the result?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the drivers are at [this location](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) if you simply put the model number in the product name box and choose linux as the operation system, also, a package named [lsb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lsb&searchon=names&suite=zesty&section=all) is required, which should be available by first [enabling the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and then issuing the command `sudo apt-get install lsb` - running `apt-cache policy lsb` indicates that version 9.20160110ubuntu5  is available for installation in Ubuntu 17.04